# How to use "Script load" instead of XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to use script load instead of using XMLHTTPRequest (because of XSS limitation).

```
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = "http://example.com/data.txt";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(s);
```

However, the content of the file is just a text file, is there a way to read the content from this loaded file?

Comment: if it isn't javascript, you can't load it with a script element.

Comment: Thx - that's what I was worried about. Any suggestion on how I could: 1) from the client side, read the content of a file from another domain 2) from the client, send back the content to the server for processing ?

Comment: Yes, implement CORS or JSONP. (both of which require access to the remote server)

Comment: But that means having the other domain content modified for my usage, which I don't have...

Comment: Then unfortunately your only option is to do the work server-side.

Comment: Ok, thank you Kevin. 
Server side is not possible as the site is blocking the IP after a while, that why I wanted to move the content grabbing client side.

Comment: well, i guess there just isn't a solution in your case then, other than through working with the remote host for a custom solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options:

1. Implement CORS on the remote host
2. Implement JSONP on the remote host
3. Use a server-side technology to get the data

Options one and two assume you are the owner of the remote host. If that isn't the case and you can't use option three, there's nothing you can do other than contact the remote host to work out a solution.